# Import Pipe in IONIC

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I created a value.pipe.ts file in pages. and imported it in app.module like:

```
import { SanitizeHtmlPipe } from '../pages/value.pipe';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    SanitizeHtmlPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: ErrorHandler,useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    IonicStorageModule,Auth,
    ApiServiceProvider,
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

My pipe file is:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'sanitizeHtml'
})
export class SanitizeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private _sanitizer:DomSanitizer) {
  }

  transform(v:string):SafeHtml {
    return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(v);
  }
}
```

But now when i run my code i am getting error as:

> Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module 'AppModule'
>       at syntaxError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:80856:34)
>       at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:95510:40
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:95508:54)
>       at JitCompiler._loadModules (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:113874:87)
>       at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:113835:36)
>       at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:113751:37)
>       at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:79692:49)
>       at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:5796:25)
>       at Object.229 (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:1689:109)

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: are you using only in this module?

Comment: @Sajeetharan. Imported this in ap.module.. which means i can use it every module i hope

Comment: adding `IonicStorageModule` to providers array seems odd

Comment: @SurajRao. I am using storage for storing values

Comment: yes..`IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),` in imports is enough..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to add a sharedModule to have all your commonly used pipes and providers

**Shared.Module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // dep modules
  ],
  declarations: [ 
    SanitizeHtmlPipe
  ],
  exports: [
    SanitizeHtmlPipe
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

and use it in your **`app.module.ts`** , as suraj mentioned remove **`IonicStorageModule`** from providers since it should be imported under modules.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SharedModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: ErrorHandler,useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    Auth,
    ApiServiceProvider,
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Where would i add a shared module? Inside app folder?

Comment: yeah, it should be inside app.module.ts

Comment: If i am adding derivatives i could i use this method?

Comment: which method you are refering to

Comment: Actually, I added `SanitizeHtmlPipe` to app.module @NgModule as mentioned in question.. But now it started working. I don't know why

Comment: yes your initial question did not have an issue, but recommended way is to create sharedmodule as i mentioned

Comment: I Created a directive which is different from question.. Do i need to add the directive in app.module @NgModule area?